# How to interrupt and direct my program where I want it to in the code by clicking a button?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, arduino-micro

I want to simulate christmas lights and the different modes of lighting it can produce by pressing a button. I tried to do this by having a button pressed which changes an int variable (1-3) which then corresponds to 1 of 3 of my if statements that each have their own code that lights the leds in a different manner. What I have noticed is that if I were to press the button while my program is in the middle of executing one of these light modes, the operation is NOT interrupted and I'd have to wait for the operation to finish before I could press the button and switch to a different mode. As you know, in actual Christmas lights, this is not the case. One can easily switch between modes with a push of a button with no delays. How can I achieve this through code? P.S. I am a newbie in Arduino. My code is written below

[image]

```
const int buttonPin =2;
int ledPin[5] = {3,5,6,9,10};
int counter = 1;
int brightness = 0;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
       pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
      Serial.println(ledPin[i]);
    }
}
void loop(){
 
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (reading != 0){
    counter++;
    if(counter == 4)
    {
      counter = 1;
    }      
  }
  
  if (counter == 1) // mode 1 of the christmas lights (default mode)
  {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(300);
  }  
  else if (counter == 2)// mode 2 of the christmas lights
  {
      for(brightness =0; brightness <= 255; brightness++)
      {
        analogWrite(3, brightness);
        analogWrite(5, brightness);
        analogWrite(6, brightness);
        analogWrite(9, brightness);
        analogWrite(10, brightness);
        delay(3);
      }
      for(brightness =255; brightness >= 0; brightness--)
      {
        analogWrite(3, brightness);
        analogWrite(5, brightness);
        analogWrite(6, brightness);
        analogWrite(9, brightness);
        analogWrite(10, brightness);
        delay(3);
      }    
  } 
  else if (counter == 3)// mode 3 of the christmas lights
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
        delay(150);
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
        delay(150);
    }
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
        delay(150);
        digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
        delay(150);
    }      
  }  
}
```

Comment: Step1: Read [Blinking without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) to replace `delay()` in your code. This will achieve what you are asking for; Step 2 as a bonus: read [Debouncing](https://learn.adafruit.com/make-it-switch/debouncing) as you will encounter this once you fix the first problem. Step 3 as another bonus: try to understand statement like `digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));` to toggle the LED,  and see how to use it to shorten and simply your code. Enjoy your learning.